# How to Toggle Tabs with jQuery, without closing adjacent tabs.

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, jquery-animate

Having a hard time figuring this one out. I have 3 tabs at the top of the page. On page load they are hidden. Each tab contains a piece of content. I want to click tab 1 and show tab 1's content, when I click tab 2, I want to display tab 2's content, etc. But, I also want to be able to click each respective tab a second time to hide the content associated.

So my desired effect is: click tab 1, show tab 1's content, click tab 2, show tab 2's content, click tab 2 again, hide tab 2's content. I've included the code I'm currently using; this hides the tabs correctly, expands them correctly, but does not toggle each tab if I click on its anchor element the way in which I desire. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$('.tabs').hide();
    $('ul.tabs li a').click(function () {
        $('.content').show();
});
```

Comment: Please post the HTML for the tabs.

Comment: I provided an image which I hope will help somewhat. The generated code is fairly hefty and would take quite some time to trim down -- I don't want to waste too much of your time. If the provided image is insufficient please let me know. I appreciate all the help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your click event for the tab itself, you want to do something like this for the subsequent click, so it'll hide/show when when the ACTIVE tab is clicked:

```
if ( $(this).hasClass("ui-state-active") ) {
    $(this).toggle();
}
```

(This solution assumes you're using jQuery UI tabs.)

Comment: This is assuming they have the jQuery ui files being loaded.

Comment: @JTSmith, wouldn't they have to be loaded if tabs are working in the first place?

Comment: How do you know he's using jQuery UI tabs?

Comment: @Marc No, you can toggle, show/hide any element without using jQuery ui library.  Without html code examples from the poster, it's hard to say exactly _what_ they are using

Comment: @JT Smith, I understand that. I suppose he could be using tabs from a different library?  I made an assumption, and I'll add that to my solution.

Comment: @Marc I'm thinking/assuming they are user created tabs rather than a plugin of sorts.  Operative word being `assume` because they still fail to post their code

Comment: It's being driven by a module for Drupal, Quicktabs, but I believe this is powered by jQuery UI.

Comment: I apologize. I'm attempting to truncate the code a bit, as there is a lot of data and it goes beyond character limit.

Comment: @Marc Good re-clarification of your answer. +1 my man as it's a good solution if the ui library is being used.

Comment: Okay, when properly implemented this actually causes the anchor link to disappear, rather than toggling the content below it. A little confused here. I also tried:

    $('ul.quicktabs-tabs li a').click(function () {
        if ( $('ul.quicktabs-tabs li').hasClass("active") ) {
       $('.quicktabs_main').toggle();
   }
     });

But it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Threaded, you are correct. But you also haven't posted your code, so I don't know how to tell you to refer to the child `DIV` that you actually want to hide.  Simple use of Firebug could probably answer that question for you though.

Comment: jQuery tab panels get a class of ".ui-tabs-panel", so you could start there.

Comment: Does this help a bit? http://postimage.org/image/gad9ypfu9/ 
I attempted to truncate the code manually but had one hell of a time doing so as there are literally an asinine amount of classes and ID's being applied to elements via Drupal's output

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure until I see the HTML, but `$('.content').toggle();` should work.

Comment: Although `$('.content')` matches all elements with that class name. Show me the HTML please.

Answer (score 0):

Can also use `.toggle()`

```
$('.tabs').hide();
$('ul.tabs li a').click(function () {
    $('.content').toggle();
});
```

If your tabs are hidden on page load, you should put this in CSS `display: none;` then use the click event

```
$('ul.tabs li a').click(function () {
    $('.content').toggle();
});
```

If having problem still using toggle, then create a unique id for each tab and do this.  The problem lies within the query:

```
$('ul.tabs li a').click(function() {
    $(this).toggle;
});
```

By using `.content` you are activating the parent element rather than its children

Comment: I've tried this using toggle, but unfortunately it's more complicated than that -- or so I assume. If I click on tab 1 twice, toggle works to show and hide that tab, but if I click on tab 1 once to show it, and then click on tab 2, the result is that it hides tab 1, instead of hiding tab 1 and showing tab 2. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: That's because `.content` is the same class name in every tab. Show the HTML for one of the tabs and we'll be able to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Again, apologies. The code is being generated by Drupal and is fairly hefty on the character count. What I can tell you from looking at it in the text editor is that each tab does have a unique ID -- and I can further create unique ID's for the content contained within.

Comment: Looking at that image of the code, what exactly are you "opening up" when you click on it?  I see no sub menu's in there.

Comment: It probably would've been more beneficial if I had paid attention and actually taken a pic of the full block of code, containing the container elements for the content...

http://postimage.org/image/gad9ypfu9/

Apologies, again!

Comment: No problem.  Try Marc's idea.  If you think the ui library is being loaded then his solution should work.  If not, it's only a line or two to add so it's easily changed/altered.

Comment: I've just started with jQuery and as a result I need a little more guidance if you don't mind taking the time; when he refers to putting it "inside" the click event, does he mean this?:
    .click(function (){insert-code-here});

Comment: This `$('ul.tabs li a').click(function ()` is your "click event" so put what he suggests inside that, in place of where you have `$('.content').show();`